# Command execution in sed while preserving unmatched part of the line

Tags: shell, sed, type-conversion

It is simple - I have a data stream with IPv4 addresses encoded into hexadecimal representation like for example 0c22384e which stands for 12.34.56.78.

I figured out sed command with substitution of captured octets into decimal numbers separated by dot.

```
echo "0c22384e" | sed -E 's/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})/printf "%d.%d.%d.%d" 0x\1 0x\2 0x\3 0x\4/eg'
```

This works with a single number BUT as soon I add some text that is not supposed to be matched, it is also passed for the execution - via printf in this case.

How can I preserve the unmatched part of the line without being passed for the execution?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: If you want to match whole lines with these IPs you may use `sed -E 's/^([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})$/...`

Comment: Example: Convert `Something 0c22384e more` into `Something 12.34.56.78 more`.

Answer (score 0):

With only one address in a line you could use

```
echo "Something 0c22384e more" |
 sed -r 's/(.*)([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})(.*)/"\1" 0x\2 0x\3 0x\4 0x\5 "\6"/' |
 xargs -n6 printf '%s%d.%d.%d.%d%s\n'
```

EDIT:
Replaced solution for one line and more addresses
with solution for more lines (assuming no '\r' in the stream):

```
echo "Something 0c22384e more 0c22385e
Second line: 0c22386e and 0c223870
Third line: 0c22388e and 0c223890
4th line: 0c2238ae and 0c2238b0" |
  sed 's/$/\r/' |
  sed -r 's/[0-9a-f]{8}/\n&\n/g' |
  sed -r 's/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})/printf '%d.%d.%d.%d' 0x\1 0x\2 0x\3 0x\4/e' |
  tr -d '\n' |
  tr '\r' '\n'
```

Comment: Indeed, this is working. Thank you. However it is still a workaround. I am surprised that the command execution in sed does not work as usual substitution of the matched part but of a whole line.

Comment: When you use `/e`, the line is not modified by the substring you ask for. The complete line is replaced by the output of a command that can be constructed with fragments of the original line.

Comment: From my point of view, sed is inconsistent in doing common substitution compared to command execution substitution.